# ios and android communication using emoticons

Tags: android, ios, titanium, emoji, emoticons

I want to create an app where users can exchange messages. The app will be for both IOS and Android. I know IOS supports Emoticons but android does not. The problem I am facing is if an ios user wants to talk to an ios user emoticons will be displayed, but if an ios user talks to an android user the emoticons will not show up. I had an idea to create a single image of many emoticons and then when an android user clicks on a part of the image it would get the x, y coordinated and then send use that image. This would work because I would map all these android custom emoticons to an ios emoticon. The problem is what if IOS changes its emoticons during an update, I would need to create all new emoticons and remap them, as well users who do not update the app after my changes will not receive the benefit and this would cause inconsistency. Is there any easier approach to this type of problem?

Answer (score 0):

Emoticons are unicode characters so they won't change. Doesn't Android support the unicode plane containing the emoticon characters?

See the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticons_%28Unicode_block%29), they are basically U+1F60F through U+1F64F.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, IOS emoticons have a lot than in that chart, they have things such as animals, planes, travel, etc. http://www.grumdrig.com/emoji-list/

Comment: Android has our own version of those same emoticons. Check your Google Hangouts app and click the smiley face.

Comment: I can only find out that android 4.4 has emoji, but not any version pre-4.4. How would I accompany these devices?